# Python in NetBeans 8.1

Tags: python, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm running NetBeans 8.1, and installed the python plugin (and jython because apparently the python plugin depends on it). However I appear to be getting away with syntax only in jython, specifically using `print` without parenthesis.

In the Python Platform Manager it only shows Jython 2.7.0. I have clicked 'new' and navigated to C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32 and selected python.exe. However I then receive a 'Invalid Python Type' error.

How do I fix this error and is it even related to my initial problem?